# NodeJS - getting Error: read ETIMEDOUT with ~3,000 http get requests

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, express, node-request

My app uses NodeJS, Express and Request.

I'm downloading a bunch of data from an API (all within the API's usage limits). It's around 3,000 requests, and they all happen fairly simultaneously.

After about 1,000 of those requests (which return data fine), I start seeing  `Error: read ETIMEDOUT` for almost every request. I can manually do a `CURL` request for the API endpoint from my terminal and it gets a response just fine.

Is this a known issue with NodeJS? Perhaps an agent / pooling issue? Or is this likely some sort of call limit on my API's end?

Comment: 3,000 simultaneous API calls is a lot; that would put a burden on the vast majority of APIs out there, not to mention the bandwidth issues on both ends, depending on how much data is involved. It's likely you're just flooding the pipes or burying the server for a moment.

Comment: @EdCottrell Hrm, they mention an hourly rate limit for their API but nothing else. it's a CRM so I would've assumed this isn't something uncommon. What's the suggested solution here, using a timeout/interval to batch the requests into more manageable chunks?

Comment: Yep. Also, since you said it's a lot of data, keep in mind that the problem might be on your end. If each response generates, say, 100k of data, that would be 300 MB of data. Even if the server can handle it, it might take so long to get back to your machine that it looks like it timed out because the pipe is full.

Comment: If all these requests are to the same endpoint, then the default http module in node.js will only make a max of N requests at a time and will queue the rest.  It's pretty easy to imagine that if you queue up 3000 of them and they're only being sent 10 at a time, that some of the other 2990 in the queue might timeout before they get their turn.  I'd suggest you only send N at a time where you will have to decide what the value of N should be.  Of course, it's also possible that you're overwhelming the server too, but I'd first make sure you don't have a problem on your end.

Comment: @jfriend00 Great responses guys, thank you.